# how does the last avatar got in the center and under it is a audio in the center too

Tags: html, css

how does the audio and the last avatar got in the center? I want the last avatar to be in the center and under it is the audio that was also in the center,

please help me thank you guys i just try  in after the  of the last avatar picture the audio progress didn't get at the center please help guys thanks a lot this is just for learning new things

and how does the last avatar picture got in the center i tried again the  but it didn't work thanks guys

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 10px solid black;
 }
 .container {
   position: relative;
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
}

 .image {
   opacity: 1;
   display: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   height: auto;
   transition: .5s ease;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
 }

 .middle {
   transition: .5s ease;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 3%;
   transform: translate(17%, -20%);
   -ms-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
   text-align: center;
 }

 .container:hover .image {
   opacity: 0.5;
 }

 .container:hover .middle {
   opacity: 1;
 }

 .text {
   background-color: #dbe0dc;
   color: black;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
 }
 .column {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 5px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
    <div class="text">sample 1</div>
  </div>
  </div> <br>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 2</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 3</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 4</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 5</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 6</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 7</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 8</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 9</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 10</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">sample 11</div>
</div></div>
</center>
<center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="wrapper">
 <audio id="mytrack" controls>
  <source src="sample audio.com" type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>
 <nav>
  <div id="defaultBar">
   <div id="progressBar"></div>
   </div>
</center>
```

Comment: While i can't really understand what is your queston,I will just point out that `display: absolute;` that you have in css class  image is not a valiid css and it should be `position:absolute;`

Comment: Consider editing your question, so that it is more clear.  Do you want to place the audio in the center of the page and after all of the avatars?

Comment: yes i wanted to place it at the center and the last avatar placed it at the center

Comment: sorry for my question

Comment: So you want to have 10 avatars in two rows and another one must be bellow them with an audio attached to it in the center?

Comment: no i want the last avatar is at the center and then the audio is under the last avatar that is in the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make as few changes as possible. Here is a quick fix to your problem. Separate the last image along with the audio div from other images. You don't need to use `center` tag you can center a element with `margin: auto`.

```css
    img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

table,
th,
td {
    border: 10px solid black;
}

.container {
    position: relative;

    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

.image {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50%;

    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 3%;
    transform: translate(17%, -20%);
    -ms-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.last {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;

}

.container:hover>.image {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover>.middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    background-color: #dbe0dc;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.rows {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <div class="rows">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 1</div>
        </div>
    </div> <br>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 7</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 8</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 9</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 10</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div>
    <div class="last container">
        <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg"
            class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">sample 11</div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="wrapper" class="last container">
        <audio id="mytrack" controls style="width: 200px">
            <source src="sample audio.com" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
        <nav>
            <div id="defaultBar">
                <div id="progressBar"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but the text appearing the image when hovering a mouse pointer is gone